# Electrical resistivity calculation of a cylindrical material

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

I have a copper rod, its diameter is 13mm, and its height is 13mm. I want to check its electrical resistivity. I have tools to give this copper a constant current by two points (the two black dots in the figure), and I can measure the electrical potential by two points (the two red dots in the figure). I was wondering how can I calculate the electrical resistivity of this copper given the information (including all dimensions of the copper)?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: For a short section of rod like what you described in which the length is comparable to the diameter, you can't just assume a 2D current flow situation. You have a full 3D problem. Your options are (1) do a full 3D computer simulation of the current flow and use that to interpret your voltage measurement, (2) run a calibration test with a material of known resistivity and having the same shape and dimensions as you copper rod section, or (3) using a longer length section of copper rod so that the current flow is 2D throughout most of the rod to a very good approximation.

Comment: Hello Tom, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! We don't really questions that are homework or exercise like here; but what you can do is show what you have tried and ask a conceptual question about the problem. If you do this, your question will be much improved. Thanks!

Comment: @heather - Not sure if this is a homework question since, as I point out above, the solution is not as simple as it may appear at first glance. This is really a 3D problem and coming up with a solution through calculations is a difficult problem.

Comment: @SamuelWeir Thanks for the suggestions!  I've bought a very long copper wire and will run some calibration tests from McMaster-Carr. I was wondering do you know if finite element simulations can solve electrical related problems well?

Comment: @heather This is not my homework. Sorry I didn't put much information here. Because I didn't find much useful information on the Internet, except the basic equations. I thought my problem couldn't be solved by thoes basic equations.

Comment: @Tom - If you're not restricted to using the very short length of copper wire that you described but can use a much longer length of wire, then that's the way to go in making a resistivity measurement as opposed to doing a finite element simulation on your present length of wire. Even if you did do a 3D finite element simulation, it would only be valid for electrodes placed exactly at the positions that you show in the figure above and any slight mis-positioning of the electrodes from their ideal positions were result in errors.

Comment: @SamuelWeir I can only fabricate samples at the given dimensions... Guess I'll combine finite element simulation and test results on know materials. Thanks!

Comment: @SamuelWeir Your comments are complete enough to be an answer.